# Can't understand why slice is used (React-native)

Tags: slice, react-native

Why is Slice used in delete function ? 
I tried the same without slice function, and the result was that I couldn't delete the last element.

```
export default class FlatListBasics extends Component {
  state = {
    data:[
            {key: 'Devin'},
            {key: 'Jackson'},
            {key: 'James'},
            {key: 'Joel'},
            {key: 'John'},
            {key: 'Jillian'},
            {key: 'Jimmy'},
            {key: 'Julie'},
          ]
};
delete(item){
     this.setState(previousState => {
     let tasks = previousState.data.slice();
     tasks.splice(item,1);
      return { data:tasks};
      });
}
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

`.slice()` will return a copy of the array. Without it, you're mutating the previous state. React depends on you not to do that in order to detect what has changed so it can recreate only the relevant parts of the template. Read more [at React Tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#why-immutability-is-important).

Comment: this is correct, when you dont use slice the state changes but the screen doesn't refresh so your changes wont be visible.